# error: file '/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10, hibernate

Sorry for janky english, as it isnt my main language.
I know theres a bunch of questions like this one but ive tried a lot of the proposed solutions and none work for me, i have dualboot with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and im no expert, but from what the bootrepair log can tell, it seems that fast reboot isnt letting windows start or something, ive tried to use remove_hiberfile but it just says it cant do it since windows is hibernating, so im probably doing something wrong.
Here's bootrepair's log:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8yZNQ4DfvP/

Comment: I don't see a problem related to Ubuntu. I see an UEFI and/or Windows problem and the 1st line from the log "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount." That is a big NO from Linux in general. Touching a hibernated Windows can destroy personal data. Please fix Windows problems with Windows tools and if needed with help from Windows users :)

Comment: Windows updates will turn fast start up back on which sets hibernation flag & prevents `sudo update-grub` from adding it to grub menu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)